# Get value from multiple elements dynamically created, (editable, drag and drop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using Jquery to drag, drop and edit some content. I use a very nice Jquery codepen (https://codepen.io/social_quotient/pen/xxXxZq)

For my personal need, I want to be able to send all created content with php. It has to be in the exact order I dropped and dragged the content. So I thing the best idea is to group all content dynamically (when individually submitted) into a div or an input for example but I got struggles with content dynamically generated and once I got it dragged, it's not working anymore.

So I started by something like this:

```
$("button#submit_titre").click(function(event) {
    var bla = $('input#titre').val();
    $('input#post_title').val(bla);
});
```

So when I click on the confirm button of the first content, it goes to a defined input. I could do that for all generated content but I don't know how to give a specific ID in order to make it work.

So is there somebody who could give me some tips to where to go because I think I'm not going to the right direction

Comment: You need to give your `<section>`s some way to identify them, but *not* a DOM ID - ie not `<section id="para1">` - rather `<section data-type="paragraph">`.  Then you can read them out using `let sections = $("section").map((e, i) => $(e).data("type"))` then you'll have an array of the section types and their rearranged order.  Do this at the time of submit and you're done.

Comment: great, thank's for the right direction